# Angulat emit does not work on addEventListener

Tags: angular

I am trapping an event in my ngAfterViewInit as below.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resetWindowHeight);
}

resetWindowHeight(){
    const element: HTMLIFrameElement = document.getElementById('frame') as HTMLIFrameElement;
    if (element) {
       this.onHeightChange.emit()  /// Error here
    }
}
```

When I try to emit an event, I get an error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit')'. How can I solve this? I want to emit when the user resizes the window

Comment: you have to initialize `onHeightChange` with `EventEmitter`

Comment: It's probably a scoping issue. Try either using anonymous function which doesn't change the scope or use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the `resetWindowHeight` is associated causes this error. This is the scope resolution issue behind the need for [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    // You can also make () => this.resetWindowHeight()
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resetWindowHeight.bind(this));
}
```